# ESP32 JTAG debugging with VSCode

Tags: esp32, jtag

recently I have bougth a ESP32 devkit and a low budget FT4232H jtag adapter which I managed to setup in VSCode using the Espressif-idf plugin.

Basically it seems to work so far. I can build, flash and monitor the ESP32 from VSCode. Also also managed to setup the debug configuration, but I am still missing some features in while debugging.

I can step through the code, watch variables and see the call stack.

[image]

But I can't see periphals, registers or memory

[image]

I guess I have to set some more options in GDB, OpenOCd or even ESP32 config but I don't know which ones.

Any ideas were i have to dig?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I dont see even local variables. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be almost there.

I have a very similar interface with the memory loading afterwards but only after stepping into certain operations.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/jtag-debugging/debugging-examples.html

Following this document produced by espressif. Memory can be accessed and stepped into using the keyboard shortcut (x) when using openOCD.

Give that a try.

Comment: X command is a Good hint, but I have no idea how to integrate/use it in vscode. After some research it seems that vscode has no memory viewer support. I will test it with eclipse later

Comment: Today I tested debuggin using Eclipse. I still can't see memory but at least can see registers. Refering to https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/jtag-debugging/debugging-examples.html there shouldn't be any problems accessing the memory..